# 'Constant is not finite! That's illegal. constant:nan' error in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm receiving the following error when I try to launch the app I'm working on. 'Constant is not finite!  That's illegal.  constant:nan'

It's a school project clone of instagram. I'm thinking the error is in the subview or possibly in the constraints created but unfortunately I'm just not seeing the issue.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

     // Before layout, calculate the intrinsic size of the labels (the size they "want" to be), and add 20 to the height for some vertical padding.
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize usernameLabelSize = [self.usernameAndCaptionLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    CGSize commentLabelSize = [self.commentLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];

    self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint.constant = usernameLabelSize.height + 20;
    self.commentLabelHeightConstraint.constant = commentLabelSize.height + 20;
    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);

    // Hide the line between cells
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds));
}

NSDictionary *viewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mediaImageView, _usernameAndCaptionLabel, _commentLabel);

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_mediaImageView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_usernameAndCaptionLabel]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_commentLabel]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_mediaImageView][_usernameAndCaptionLabel][_commentLabel]" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];



    self.imageHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mediaImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
    self.imageHeightConstraint.identifier = @"Image height constraint";

    self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_usernameAndCaptionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
    self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint.identifier = @"Username and caption label height constraint";

    self.commentLabelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_commentLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:100];
    self.commentLabelHeightConstraint.identifier = @"Comment label height constraint";

    [self.contentView addConstraints:@[self.imageHeightConstraint, self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint, self.commentLabelHeightConstraint]];


}
```

Comment: NaN is "not a number". You might be dividing by 0 somewhere.

Comment: have you tried to narrow down where the issue is occurring? A helpful practice is to comment out code until you find the line causing the problem. also you could use the debugger or just print out the values being assigned and see what is going on.

Comment: What Paxic said, and also it's not clear if you're posting this code because you *know* the error is here, or because you think it might be somewhere here. If the debugger is not showing you exactly where the issue is, then as they say, remove chunks of code until it launches OK. It will be a divide-by-zero somewhere, but you'll need to sort out what code triggers it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  **Post the *exact and complete* exception message, and the exception stack trace.**

Comment: sorry for the confusion everyone. When I used the add Exception break point it was pointing me to the following code `self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);`

Comment: @OFRBG  you were correct looks like I was dividing by 0.  I never set the height of the cell and that's why mediaItem was returning 0. Thanks for the help people and I'll make sure to include the complete error next time when I post to make the code a lot clearer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I only see one place where you are doing division:

```
self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
```

Set a breakpoint on this line and see what `self.mediaItem.image.size` looks like.

Comment: Thanks @steve_sch I found the issue I was dividing by zero and never set mediaItem to return a value. Once I updated this everything worked as expected , thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you, I was dividing by zero as well.

Comment: The same issue :D! thanks...  I was dividing by zero as well

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Saved hours!